# ODBC permission error in partial trust xbap app

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0, xbap

I am developing a partial trust xbap app . but when i try to open the odbc connection then it gives me the error of permission . the error is :

```
    Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
```

How to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not experienced in developing xbap with partial trust, but answer to this question as indicated [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/842787cb-e1b3-4a42-9e52-1c93c3675ba7/partial-trust-wpf-app) is **you can't access database directly in partial trust wpf application**. Solution to this problem is to delegate responsibility of accessing database to web service. And your xbap simply consume that web service.